# Display different data in input form field instead of value in Angular6

Tags: html, typescript, forms, angular6

I am using material and form in a component in angular 6.

```
 <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="autoForm"
          formControlName="formg">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" panelWidth="200">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let val of list | async" [value]="val.code"
            (onSelectionChange)="changed($event)">
            <span>{{val.code}} - {{val.name}}</span>
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Now the value shown on textbox is the code number only. I would like to display it as "val.code-val.name" . Shall we do it from html itself? without changing the form values? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? What exactly you want to show in html?

Comment: drop down now shows as : 001-CodeOne, 002-CodeTwo, etc. On selecting one option, input text box shows 001, I would Like to show it as "001-CodeOne"